# How to make powershell emit an error on undeclared command line arguments

Tags: powershell

Given the following `script.ps1`

```
Param([switch]$Foo)

Write-Output $Foo
```

How can I make it error on undeclared arguments, such as `script.ps1 -Bar`?

I can write my own code to do it by interpreting `$args`, but it seems like powershell should be able to do it for me, as it already parses the arguments.

Comment: see `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` and also `[Parameter(ParameterSetName=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to only accept declared parameters and error on unexpected extra arguments, **you must make your script/function an *advanced* one**, which can be achieved as follows:

- *explicitly*: decorate the `param(...)` block with a `[CmdletBinding(...)]` attribute.
- *implicitly*: decorate any of the individual parameters with a `[Parameter(...)]` attribute.

For instance (using a *script block* (`{ ... }`) for simplicity; the same applies to *scripts* and *functions*):

```
PS> & { Param([switch] $Foo)  } -Bar
# !! NO error (or output) - undeclared -Bar switch is quietly IGNORED.

# Using the [CmdletBinding()] attribute ensures that only declared
# parameters can be used.
PS> & { [CmdletBinding()] Param([switch] $Foo)  } -Bar
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Bar'. # OK - error.
...
```

See [`Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced)